# Chart is empty upon initialization

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I have a single chart showing on my site. Viewers can then click links beside the chart in order to change the chart data. My problem is that the data will not show in the chart upon initialization - only if you start clicking the buttons beside the chart will the data load. I load data into the charts using JSON. I have been told that the problem might be that the JSON data is loaded after the chart is first displayed (an asynchronous problem), but I don't know how to fix this.

Below is the code I use for setting the first chart I have (chartOptions.chart1) into the "container" div. This will initialize the chart structure but it will not call my data - the data will only show if I start clicking the div-links.

```
$('chart').ready(function() {

    //common options
  Highcharts.setOptions({
    chart: {
      marginRight: 0
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
      bar: {
        pointPadding: .01
      },
      column: {
        borderWidth: 0.5
      },
      line: {
        lineWidth: 1
      },
    },
    series: [{
        color: '#027ff7',
        data: []
    }]
  });
      $('#container').highcharts(chartOptions.chart1);
      chart = $('#container').highcharts();

      $(document).on('click', '.chart-update', function() {
        $('div').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
            chart.destroy();
        $('#container').highcharts(chartOptions[$(this).data('chartName')]);
        chart = $('#container').highcharts();
      });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <span class="wrapper">
        <span class="block chart"><div id="container" style="width:400px;height:300px;float:left;"></div></span>
        <span class="block buttons">
            <div id="divchart" class="chart-update selected" data-chart-name="chart1">Chart1</div>
            <div id="divchart" class="chart-update" data-chart-name="chart2">Chart2</div>
        </span>
    </span>
</body>
```

So I am wondering if I can use something else instead of the

```
    $('#container').highcharts(chartOptions.chart1);
```

in order to have the first chart initialized in the container-div when visitors first enter the site? Of if there is some javascript code that will automatically trigger the on-"click" part - since this works just fine.

Comment: what about copying the json inline? then update using the server call?

Comment: I'm quite confused about your code, will you specifiy the process per code blocks?to help us to better understand your logic. And also check `chartOptions.chart1` if this returns the chart1 object that you populated

Comment: I have now shortened the code I provided in the question. The chartOptions.chart1 is my first chart and chartOptions.chart2 is the second (i actually have some 20+ chart-series). All data display just fine when users click the div-links. It is only upon first opening the site that the default chart (chart1) shows up without the series data.

Comment: Your code shows you are not loading any data at all on initial load of page - so of course it is empty. Why not do as Jonas said an have a default series already loaded up when the page is loaded?